# is there a direct explanation for each google-ads.yaml item?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, integration, google-ads-api

I am looking for collect data from Google ADS API into GCP by using Python scripts and it requires to fill these items for authentication in the google-ads.yaml file:

```
developer_token:
client_id:
client_secret:
refresh_token:
login_customer_id:
```

I was able to fill these items by asking people in my company or generating it with google python scripts in GitHub but I need to understand the role of each, the docs seems to be disperse with a long learning path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this [guidebook](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/#configuration-file-setup) to make your google-ads.yaml file. And for the sample role you provided, below are the definitions of each but you can check this [sample template](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/main/google-ads.yaml) for more details about it.

**Developer token**

A developer token is required when making requests to the Google Ads API regardless of whether you're using the OAuth2 or Service Account configurations. To obtain a developer token see: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token

> developer_token: INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE

**OAuth2 configuration**

The below configuration parameters are used to authenticate using the recommended OAuth2 flow. For more information on authenticating with OAuth2 see:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview

> client_id: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_HERE

> client_secret: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE

> refresh_token: INSERT_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE

**Login customer ID configuration**

Required for manager accounts only: Specify the login customer ID used to authenticate API calls. This will be the customer ID of the authenticated manager account. It should be set without dashes, for example: 1234567890 instead of 123-456-7890. You can also specify this later in code if your application uses multiple manager account + OAuth pairs.

> login_customer_id: INSERT_LOGIN_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE